# latest angular with angular-animate

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm rebuilding an application from the ground up that started as a jquery/bootstrap/kendo ui mess, but will be an angular(2/4)/kendo app going forward.

I was using jQuery slideUp/slideDown:

```
$('#id').slideUp('slow');
$('#id').slideDown('slow');
```

to show and hide div contents on an as-needed basis. I found angular-animate, which seems like it's a good fit, but I'm thinking angular-animate is for Angular 1.x? To add ngAnimate as a dependency, one writes:

```
angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-animate')]);
```

Can this be used in the latest angular, or is there a workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its animate in Latest Angular.

```
npm i @angular/animations
```

Enable animation in main module like this:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Include animation like this:

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';
```

Here is the link which has code samples as well.

https://angular.io/guide/animations

Since you are coming from Angular 1. This will be a gud starting point:

http://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/nganimate-angular-2-animate/

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sandman thanks for the guidance. I am new here so still learning what and how things should be done. Will keep that in mind from now on. Thanks again.